# OutOfMemoryError for Bitmap(List View)

Tags: android, github, bitmap

I have read much about out of memory in android due to Bitmap and took various steps to prevent it but it keeps knocking endlessly. Here is my code :

**CODE :**

```
    in = httpConn.getInputStream();
   BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   options.inPurgeable=true; 
   options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
   options.inSampleSize = 1;
   options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
   image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
```

I am able to load around 15 images that are with a dimension 640*640. After that it throws me a OutOfMemoryError in the log cat. I have also implemented a external library(from [GitHub](https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore)) for **"PullToRefresh"** functionality. So obviously that involves a custom list view. Is there any way to avoid this Memory issue.

**NOTE :** I have already read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). I have also implemented those methods but it still fails to stand up.

Can I use **Fragments with List View** to avoid this memory issue ? Or, is am I missing something ? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the  `options.inSampleSize = 1;` to `options.inSampleSize = 4;`

And also do

```
bitmap.reCycle();
```

Comment: Setting the inSampleSize to 4 reduces my image size !! Will try bitmap.recycle() and get back to ya.

Comment: change samples into 2, and check image

Comment: That gets me to a decent size but setting it to 1 is what meets my expectations. I am also well aware that inSampleSize should always be set to powers of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Now image loading time from internet has many solution. You may also use this library "Android-Query" https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading .It will give you all the required activity.Make sure what you want to do ? and read library wiki page. and solve image loading restriction.

This is my code:-

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }

     ImageView imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
           AQuery aq = new AQuery(convertView);

           String imageUrl = "http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/vikispot/android-w.png";

          aq.id(imageview).progress(this).image(imageUrl, true, true, 0, 0, new BitmapAjaxCallback(){

                   @Override
                   public void callback(String url, ImageView iv, Bitmap bm, AjaxStatus status){

                       iv.setImageBitmap(bm);


                   }

           });

    }
    return v;
}
```